# Create report of group count

Tags: reports

I would like to create a report which simply has the total number of people in a particular group. The reason for a report rather than just going to manage groups and looking is that I want to email this number to the client weekly preferably automatically. Under reports I couldn't see that I could select groups. Can I do this using reports? Or is there another way (I did look at automatign an sql query but the group is a smart group and I can't see how to count that)

I'm open to any solutions!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reports you can use the Filters tab to select on only the members who are in the group you are interested in. You can create a new report that has the filter so you can use this for the automatic mailing. This will send the whole list if group members (you can cut down the fields. It will have the number of group members at the bottom of the pdf, but will also list all the members (which you may not want).

Comment: Thanks Mick that will work although possibly not as GDPR mindful as I would like!